# Civicrm admin menu - can it be made to open submenus on hover rather than on click?

Tags: menu

In Drupal's admin menu, and nearly any drop down menu I've seen, you simply hover over the highest level parent items and their children drop down.

However, in Civicrm (4.6)'s admin menu, you have to click the parent item before the child will drop down. But then all subsequent child menus open on hover.

I'm watching our admin volunteers be endlessly confused by this. They think that if they click on the main parent menu items they'll leave the page they're on. Or they think there is no sub menu and don't investigate further.

So, is it possible to make the main menu items' sub menus open on hover rather than on click?

I'm on Drupal 7.54 and Civi 4.6.24. Thanks!